# Error in optim : L-BFGS-B needs a finite value of fn

Tags: r, optim

I'm using the optim function to optimize 5 coefficients. I use this function to do this :

```
min.RSS = function(data, par){
  sum(
    ((data$CCI) - 
      10^(par[1]+par[2]*data$Landsat +
         par[3]*data$Landsat^2 +
         par[4]*data$Landsat^3 + 
         par[5]*data$Landsat^4))^2, na.rm=TRUE)
}
```

The following coefficients are used in this function later

```
OC3 <- function(coeff, landsat_values) {
  chloa <- 10^(coeff[1] + coeff[2]*landsat_values +
                    coeff[3]*landsat_values^2 +
                    coeff[4]*landsat_values^3 +
                    coeff[5]*landsat_values^4)
  return(chloa)
}
```

The data$CCI values are quite low so when I'm using the other optimisation method of optim the results of the OC3 function is always 0. I wanted to fix this by putting some upper and lower values to my optimization like this :

```
optimization_LBFGSB <-  optim(par=c(0.30963,-2.40052,1.28932,0.52802,-1.33825), fn=min.RSS, data = data, method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = c(-3,-3,-3,-3,-3), upper = c(3,3,3,3,3))
```

I don't know how to by-pass this problem

Comment: We probably can't provide a useful answer without a [mcve]. You should be able to get an equivalent fit for this model using `glm(CCI ~ poly(Landsat, 4, raw=TRUE), family = gaussian(link="log"))` without the hassle of using `optim` to minimize the sums of squares (although the parameters will be on the natural log scale rather than log10 - you could convert them by multiplying by `log(10)` ...)

Comment: Maybe this could help to provide an useful answer.
My data are organized like this : CCI is a 1600000 column with data going from 0 to 500 with a mean value of 0.48. The Landsat value are the same size with data going 2323 to -9200 with a mean value of 0.66

Comment: Are you saying that you have 1.6 million observations/rows of data? You will almost certainly want to use the `glm` trick above, and possibly the `fastglm` package ...

Comment: It might help a lot just to scale your Landsat values by a factor of 1e3 or 1e4 (so that raising them to the fourth power doesn't lead to ginormous values).

Comment: Got this error : glm does not converge

Comment: I don't underdtabd what you mean by scale my data. If I multiply my landsat data the relationship is not the same antmore

Comment: Is there any chance we can have access to your data, or that you can show us how to simulate some data that resemble your data sufficiently well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example .  Scaling your Landsat values by a factor of 1e4 will change nothing about your model fit but the units in which the results are expressed; you can always divide the coefficients by the same factor after you've fitted the model, in order to get the coefficients you would have gotten from the unscaled data.

Comment: Is it okay with you if I export my dataset as csv and share it with you ?

Comment: Yes. Normally posting data somewhere everyone can get it is **strongly** preferred on SO, but I'll accept it in this case.  (I'm happy to accept an RDS file instead, which will be much smaller than a CSV ...)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help ! Here is a link to the csv file containing almost all the dataset (dataset was too big to fit into one excel file) : https://uclouvain-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/aurelien_lengrand_student_uclouvain_be/EfASmwopmfNHroGCNLsawFABJsXQ41HAJgTcxajHqgNvkw?e=sjyooH

Comment: I tought I could add some context for a better understanding of what I'm trying to do here. I'm trying to compute chlorophyll-a concentration thanks to Landsat 8 images in order to study the water quality spatiotemporal varibility in the estuarine areas of Lake Tanganyika.  To do so I'm trying to optimise the OC3 algorithm with CCI Lake chlorophyll-a concentration.